# How to make an element not pass above the table header while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a table with a scroll inside and on the end of every row is a sticky icon that opens a menu, the icon is only visible when the row it belongs to is hovered, but while scrolling the page doesn't consider the mouse to be moving and thinks it is still hovering the original row, this makes so the icon remains visible and goes over the header. How can I fix this?

[image: Table with first row being hovered]

[image: Scrolling down]

Code for the header, Th has relevant styling but the others have only colors and sizes:

```
<Thead>
  {header.map(item => (
    <Th
      key={item.key}
      variant={item.key}
      onClick={handleSelectColumnToShorting}
      selected={selected}
    >
      <ContainerThItems>
        {handleSortingIcon(item.key)}
        <DividerIcon />
        <ThText>{item.name.toUpperCase()}</ThText>
      </ContainerThItems>
    </Th>
  ))}
</Thead>
```

Th has

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

For the body:

```
<Tbody>
   {data.map((dataRaw, index) => (
     <Tr key={dataRaw.id} data>
       {header.map(column => (
         <Td key={column.key}>{dataRaw[column.key]}</Td>
       ))}
       <DropMenuContainer>
         <DropMenu
           open={isOpen}
           setOpen={setIsOpen}
           index={index}
           side="left"
           opened={opened}
           setOpened={setOpened}
           title={language.actions}
           contents={[
             <Li
               variant="dropMenu"
               onClick={() => {
                 handleNavigate(dataRaw);
               }}
             >
               {language.edit}
             </Li>,
             <Li
               variant="dropMenu"
               onClick={async () => {
                 await deleteEmployee(dataRaw.id);
                 setIsOpen(false);
               }}
             >
               {language.remove}
             </Li>,
           ]}
         >
           <Tooltip content={language.options}>
             <Icon index={index} onClick={handleOpen} />
           </Tooltip>
         </DropMenu>
       </DropMenuContainer>
     </Tr>
   ))}
</Tbody>
```

With the relevant stylign being:

```
position: sticky;
right: 10px;
```

Comment: Have you tried overflow: hidden; on the tbody container?

Comment: @jae yes, I also tried giving them z indexes.

Comment: If i understood correctly, the icon on the right has a position: sticky style on it? Then you can adjust the top: value to be farther than your Thead, doing so should make it not get over the THead

Comment: @Jae no because it is not a single button, the rows are created on a map that adds the button at the end of every row, so if I put a top then all buttons would jump to the same position at the top.

Comment: It also just didn't work in general